# How to count number of 1 and 0 in the matrix?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, computer-vision

I have an image of which I cut out only one column. After that I made it to be logical so there are be only 0 and 1 in this column.

Suppose my values in this column are

```
1111000110000000000000011111111
```

I want to count the length of each block of ones or each block of zeros.

The result would be

```
1 - 4 (first 1)
0 - 3 (first 0)
1 - 2 
and so on...
```

I know only count for the entire column but I can't do it for each distinct block. Anyone please help me.

Comment: @Shai How is the [tag:vectorization] tag related to this?

Comment: @EitanT - solution is via vectorization and not a loop

Comment: @Shai But the question is not about vectorization _per se_... I think that this tag should be reserved for questions that regard implementations specifically aimed at vectorizing code. If your answer happens to be vectorized, it's good, but that shoudn't be the reason for retagging. Most of the answers to the MATLAB questions here can be vectorized, but that doesn't mean that they all should be under this tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let `vec` be a **row** vector (1-by-`n`) of zeros and ones, then you can use the following code

```
rl = ( find( vec ~= [vec(2:end), vec(end)+1] ) );
data =  vec( rl );
rl(2:end) = rl(2:end) - rl(1:end-1);
```

`rl` will give you the number of consecutive zeros and ones, while `data` will tell you for each block if it is zero or one.

This question is closely related to [run length coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).

Demo:

```
vec = [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1];
rl = ( find( vec ~= [vec(2:end), vec(end)+1] ) );
data =  vec( rl ),
rl(2:end) = rl(2:end) - rl(1:end-1),

data =
     1     0     1     0     1

rl =
     4     3     2    14     8
```

Comment: Thank you. I already try it but i got an error. Is it because of my vec is n-by-1 not 1-by-n ? Error is "Error using horzcat CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent."

Comment: if your vector is `n`-by-1 you can simply transpose it using `vec = vec.';`

Comment: yes, it's exactly what i want. But can i ask you more that if i look only rl so how can i know that each one is 1 or 0? Any idea?

Comment: @BowHouse `data` will give you the info you need. see my edit and example.

Comment: Oh i see. Thank you so much Shai ^^. By the way, what is the function called? i mean in the matlab, i'm quite new to matlab.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/255034 this link i already seen and try it but i think it is count for the entire matrix and count only 1. For your code is work only 1-by-n matrix?

Comment: @BowHouse my code works only for 1-by-`n` vectors. It counts any contiguous chunks (not only 1's and 0's). If you want to process the entire matrix you can stack it into a vector: `vec = mat(:)';`

Comment: if i want to put the coordinate(x,y) of each data only the first one of each block, how can i modify it. Example: vec = [**1** 1 1 1 **0** 0 0 **1** 1 **0** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **1** 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]; i want to keep the coordinate of the first number of each block of 1 and 0. I will use this when i find the maximum count of 1 and 0 in this vector and i want to know the coordinate of it